# PleskDBException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002)

Tags: mysql, sockets, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, plesk

After a recovery of my VServer i am no longer able to login into Plesk Panel. Plesk shows me the error message mentioned in the title of this topic.

Details:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit + Plesk 12.5 / Virtual Server from Strato.de

I've checked also mysql syslogs and seems that something doesn't work as it should.

After i have entered

```
grep mysql /var/log/syslog | tail -50
```

i got the following result:

Aug 12 00:16:58 h2600744 /etc/init.d/mysql[29323]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Aug 12 00:16:58 h2600744 /etc/init.d/mysql[29323]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Aug 12 00:16:58 h2600744 /etc/init.d/mysql[29323]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Aug 12 00:16:58 h2600744 /etc/init.d/mysql[29323]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

Could anyone provide help me to get this solved and therewith Plesk and my website running again? Thanks.

Comment: The socket will not exist if `mysqld` refuses to start. Check if the data directory is completely restored/recovered. If not, you will need to recover it.

Comment: It seems you're right the directory has not been completely restored. Can you help how or which command i have to use to get this solved?

Comment: Could you check if directory `/var/lib/mysql-files` exists?

Comment: Do you have a backup of the data directory? Restore the content from the backup.